# Maven: How to include ${project.version} in multi-module project

Tags: java, xml, maven

I am using `maven 3.2.1`

```
 mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T09:37:52-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.1/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_55, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

My module structure

```
projectA/
        pom.xml
        core/
             pom.xml
             business/
                     pom.xml
             persistence/
                     pom.xml
             rest/
                     pom.xml
       federated_services/
                     pom.xml
```

**ProjectA/pom.xml**

```
    <groupId>com.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>${global.version}</version>
    <properties>
        <global.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</global.version>
    </properties>
```

**core/pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.org</groupId>
    <version>${global.version}</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Things are fine until here meaning **core/xml** can find `${project.version}`. But when I do

**persistence/pom.xml**

```
   <parent>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.org</groupId>
        <version>${global.version}</version>
        <relativePath>../../</relativePath>
    </parent>
```

The pom complains

```
[ERROR]   The project com.org:persistence:${global.version} (/Users/harith/IdeaProjects/project/core/persistence/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact com.org:core:pom:${global.version} from/to local central mirror (http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/repository/public): Illegal character in path at index 68: http://maven.corp.org.com:9999/repository/public/com/org/core/${global.version}/core-${global.version}.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

**Question**
- How can I have **persistence/pom.xml** inherit `${project.version}` from **projectA/pom.xml**?

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, just don't include a version in the child; it'll inherit it. If you have to specify a version (Roo is notorious for throwing tantrums with valid POMs it doesn't approve of), you can either specify the parent version with the property or use `${project.parent.version}` for the child's version. Also look at the `versions` plugin, which will set the version on a whole hierarchy at once.

Answer (score 2):

First in general you can't use properties in versions:

ProjectA/pom.xml

```
  <groupId>com.org</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Second you shouldn't need to use relative path in your childs:
core/pom.xml

```
<parent>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.org</groupId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
```

This brings me to the point if you have a persistence/pom.xml

core
        com.org
        1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Done use things like `<relativePath>../../</relativePath>` this is usually an indicator that your structure is wrong.

BUT: [Starting with Maven 3.2.1 you can use special properties](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html) to define the versions you like. [The following placeholders are allowed in versions:](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5576)

```
${revision}, ${changelist}, and ${sha1}
```

This means if you like you can use them but only with Maven 3.2.1 so you need to change it to things like this:

ProjectA/pom.xml

```
  <groupId>com.org</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>${revision}</version>
```

and in core:

```
<parent>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.org</groupId>
  <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
```

But this means you need to call maven everytime like this:

```
mvn -Drevision=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT clean package
```

which will work. You have to be carefull if you use your project within Eclipse etc. Apart from the above i can not recommend to use it this way.

Comment: What do you mean, you can't use properties in versions? I've been using them since Maven 2. They just have to be locally resolvable.

Comment: This looks okay, however pom.xml's still keep `${revision}` variable but not snapshots(effective) while deploying to nexus, which creates dependency resolution error when we use a module as a dependecy.

Comment: See my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/64958428/413032