# How to replace version number in Maven submodule pom.xml files?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have a multimodule maven project, sub modules get version number from a parent project property and artifacts are being created well.

My problem is having `${global.version}` variable in submodules' pom.xml in nexus repo.
`commons-GOLD.jar` successfully take place in nexus by getting version number (GOLD) from parent project. However, it's pom.xml file in nexus point `${global.version}` instead of GOLD and when I add commons-gold as dependency mvn try to pull `cenatral/myProj.parent/$%7Bglobal.version%7D/myProj.parent-$%7Bglobal.version%7D.pom`

MyProject parent project pom.xml

```
<version>${global.version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>commons</module>
    <module>module2</module>
and so on

<properties>
    <!-- Unique entry point for version number management -->
    <global.version>GOLD</global.version>
</properties>
```

Commons module pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.hmg</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproj.parent</artifactId>
    <version>${global.version}</version>
</parent>
```

I would like to have above `${global.version}` be replaced with the property coming from parent pom.xml. Even though effective pom has the right value, nexus has raw pom and that cause maven command fail while resolving dependencies.

Tried overriding it but this didn't work.

`mvn '-Dglobal.version=GOLD' dependency:tree`

Or is there a way to [How to ignore parent pom for dependency resolution?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-ignore-parent-pom-for-dependency-resolution/6155)

GOLD artifact is there.

[image: artifact creation]

POM.xml contains variable, which cause dependency resolution issue.

[image: pom.xml content]

If I use commons as a dependency in another project with version 1.0.0 or GOLD, regardless of version it seeks for ${version} because  of its pom in nexus.

XDrive:> **Failed to collect dependencies** at com.xyz:common:jar:1.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.xyz:common:jar:1.0.0: **Failure to find com.xyz:myProj.parent:pom:${revision}**
in http://10.80.100.155:8085/repository/myProj-group/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: The only to get that correctly working is to use one of the three defined variables `${revision}`, `${sha1}` and `${changelist}` which are described in [ci friendly](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html). Read the documentation to the final end to get things correctly working. Apart from that you can use the versions-maven-plugin without defining any property.  Apart from that you can use the release plugin which increments the versions number and there is usually no need to define a property (only in particular cases)...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23263262/413032 in this answer it says the same. Actually I used the `${revision}`, however the problem is in nexus we have `${revision}`  variable this time instead of the package I passed in command line. `mvn '-Drevision=GOLD'`. Artifacts are okay only pom.xml under it is problem.

Comment: Then you have to setup'ed it correctly as I mentioned to read the documentation till the end. Have setup flatten-maven-plugin ? I suppose it is not ...

Comment: Ah BTW I missed one point. You should use Maven 3.6.3 to build and not maven versions lower...Apart from that I strongly recommend not to use a version `GOLD` which is not a version number ... something like `1.0.0` or `2.3.4` or `5.6.7.89.2` ...

Comment: My mvn is 3.6.0 :) It's midnight here. I'll check tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Comment: `${revision}`? are you using maven-flatten-plugin?

Comment: Updated to 3.6.3, flatten plugin is also added to parent. Jars are being created fine. However, if I use a module as dependency in another project, it's still resolving variable name from the pom ad searching for a wrong path.

Comment: @khmarbaise I saw your comment in similar question, I didn't need their solution flatten did it :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/33254495/413032

Comment: @khmarbaise issue is solved and upgrading mvn to 3.6.3 and removing other plugins but maven-flatten-plugin finally worked for me. You may write an answer and I'll happily accept it.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is simply that the usage of [flatten-maven-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) is not done correctly.

Furthermore you can only use only the following properties in relationship with this setup:

- ${revision}
- ${sha1}
- ${changelist}

Apart from that you can use the versions-maven-plugin without defining any property. Apart from that you can use the release plugin which increments the versions number and there is usually no need to define a property (only in particular cases

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want [this plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) and usage, for example:

```
mvn versions:set -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=1.2.3
```

this will update *all* versions in all modules.

Comment: Thank you very much. I saw that plugin actually. What I want to see in nexus is submodule's effective pom.xml. I only need modules' jars, however mvn fails while trying to resolve dependency because of searching with variable instead of actual tag.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz I don't get it, just get rid of `${global.version}` entirely and manage versions via that plugin, only.

Comment: You're right, actually we're already planning it on our jenkins. I just tried to find a workaround for current problem.